# svn repository checkout without branches

Tags: svn, version-control

I have to checkout a repository that has 8 branches which I don't wont to download each branch size ~400MB. Only need to checkout the folder structure and the trunk.

```
repo/trunk
repo/tags/<do not download content of this directory>
repo/branches/<do not download content of this directory>
```

Any idea? Prefer command line use.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to use Subversion's [sparse directories](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html) feature.

```
svn co --depth immediates URL_TO_REPOSITORY PATH_TO_WORKING_COPY
svn update --set-depth infinity PATH_TO_WORKING_COPY/trunk
```

Or, just check out the `trunk` directory, if you're not going to work with the tags or branches at all.

Comment: the 'or' part is the real sauce.  check out the trunk, `svn co http://svn-server/repo/trunk repo`

Comment: There may be a legitimate need to have the "stub" of the other 2 directories locally.