# How can I block some directories in an svn trunk from getting pulled?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have one master trunk that has a lot of folders. I want to pull down about 20 of those folders but ignore the other 40.

(I don't want to manually checkout those 20 folders as separate trunks)

I don't think using ignores will work in this case.

Is this possible?

I need a solution for both Linux and Windows (TortoiseSVN & command line).

Technically, I already have all of the subfolders pulled and I want to be able to delete them but not have them get re-pulled next update.

Comment: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [svn repository checkout without branches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610783/svn-repository-checkout-without-branches)